# Keep user IP after using Pipe in express

Tags: express, request, pipe

After a pipe redirection I am lossing my user IP.

Before redirection (first express server):

```
app.use('/api', function(req, res) {
  var url = 'http://localhost:4000/' 
  console.log('ip Before:', req.ip);
  req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res)
})
```

After redirection (second express server `http://localhost:4000/`):

```
function loggingMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  console.log('IP AFTER: ', req.ip)
  next();
}
server.express.use(loggingMiddleware);
```

Result:

```
ip Before: ::ffff:172.56.42.154
IP AFTER:  ::ffff:127.0.0.1
```

How can I 'pass' IP `::ffff:172.56.42.154` after doing the `pipe()`

Answer (score 0):

If I use a proxy (https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy):

```
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy')
app.use('/api', proxy('http://localhost:4000/', {
  proxyReqOptDecorator: function(proxyReqOpts, srcReq) {
    proxyReqOpts.headers['x-forwarded-for'] = srcReq.ip
    return proxyReqOpts
  }
}))
```

and in the server (port: 4000), I have:

```
function loggingMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  console.log('IP AFTER: ', req.ip)
  console.log('x-forwarded-for:', req.header('x-forwarded-for'))
  next();
}
server.express.use(loggingMiddleware);
```

Result:

```
ip Before: ::ffff:172.56.42.154
IP AFTER:  ::ffff:127.0.0.1
x-forwarded-for: ::ffff:172.56.42.154
```